# Docker container not using its own java but of jenkins server

Tags: docker, jenkins, build, devops

I have created a docker images and this image uses java 1.7.0_72 for compilation. My jenkins server has java 1.8.0_162 installed and also it  has a dir for 1.8.0_162 at /usr/java/default
now when i start the job, the compilation fails with "javac: target release 1.7 conflicts with default source release 1.8"
i found that docker container starts picking java 1.8.0_162 in place of 1.7.0_72
what can i do so that docker contaioner uses java 1.7.0_72 which is installed on docker image?

Details on jenkins server:

```
ls -l /usr/java
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root        16 Sep  1  2017 default -> /usr/java/latest
drwxr-xr-x  8   10  143      4096 Apr  3  2018 jdk1.8.0_162
-r--r--r--  1 root root 189816073 Apr  3  2018 jdk-8u162-linux-x64.tar.gz
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        22 Aug 11 07:51 latest -> /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_162
```

Details on docker container:

```
[root@817144324bea /]# java -version
java version "1.7.0_72"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_72-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.72-b04, mixed mode)
[root@817144324bea /]# which java
/usr/bin/java
[root@817144324bea /]# ls -l /usr/bin/ | grep java
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root          28 Aug  7 11:31 ant -> /usr/java/apache-ant/bin/ant
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root          25 Aug  7 11:22 jar -> /usr/java/default/bin/jar
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root          26 Aug  7 11:22 java -> /usr/java/default/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root          27 Aug  7 11:22 javac -> /usr/java/default/bin/javac
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root          29 Aug  7 11:22 javadoc -> /usr/java/default/bin/javadoc
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root          28 Aug  7 11:22 javaws -> /usr/java/default/bin/javaws
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root          30 Aug  7 11:22 jcontrol -> /usr/java/default/bin/jcontrol
[root@817144324bea /]#
[root@817144324bea /]# ls -l /usr/java/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   26 Aug  7 11:28 apache-ant -> /usr/java/apache-ant-1.8.0
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Feb  1  2010 apache-ant-1.8.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Aug  7 11:22 default -> /usr/java/latest
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 Aug  7 11:22 jdk1.7.0_72
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 Aug  7 11:22 latest -> /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_72
```

While running job on this docker container via jenkins, we have passed below volumes for container:
In docker template, volumes passed to image container are:

```
/usr/local/accurev:/usr/local/AccuRev
/imageGen:/imageGen
/data/Repository:/data/Repository
/usr/java/default:/usr/java/default
/var/lib/jenkins:/var/lib/jenkins
/public/jenkins:/public/Jenkins
```

Can anyone please suggest how i can make sure that container picks java 7 and not java 8 ?

Comment: Can you include the relevant pipeline code in the question?  The bind mount of `/usr/java/default` seems like a good first thing to check (depending on your pipeline code, you might not need any of these bind mounts at all).

Comment: we are not using pipeline here, we are using docker container as slave agents. And if i dont pass this /usr/java/default volume, then the container does not start.